# I would like to match the data of two columns in two different excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two excel WORKBOOK (WB)

In excel WB 1, I have column for student IDs and Advisor name.
In excel WB 2, I have IDs to be matched to WB 1 IDs if the Advisor name is "John" to show "TRUE' in a column in WB2.

Can you pls tell me what are the formulas to try AND EXPLAIN THE COMPONENTS OF THE FORMULA? 
aTTACHED IS THE SCREENSHOT OF DATA.
pLEASE NOTE ITS IN DIFFERENT EXCEL WORKBOOKS NOT SHEETS.

Comment: First thing to mention here is that the workbooks would need to be open for the INDEX formula to pick up the information from it. otherwise, formula is the same as the naming convention you have used below.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your provided formula I will run you through the minor change that will make this work:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C7:C17&"John",'[wORKBOOK1 NAME]SHEET1'!$A$2:$A$13&'[wORKBOOK1 NAME]SHEET1'!$B$2:$B$13,0)),"True","False")`

This of course is assuming that the Forenames are in `$B$2:$B$13`...

What this is doing is simply forming a string value of the ID with the Forname stuck onto the back of it. MATCH will reference an array of values that it creates from the criteria within itself - the ID with the Forename.

The match formula will work in the same way, returning an integer representing the index location within the array when the match is found.

I will point out that the formula does not accept an array for the first argument, so currently only the first cell is being searched... You will want to update the formula and perhaps have this as a column checking each individual ID:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C7&"John",'[wORKBOOK1 NAME]SHEET1'!$A$2:$A$13&'[wORKBOOK1 NAME]SHEET1'!$B$2:$B$13,0)),"True","False")`

If you wanted this as just one formula it gets a bit more complicated as you must form an array using an if statement and Evaluate against that array:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,IF(C7:C17&"John"='[wORKBOOK1 NAME]SHEET1'!$A$2:$A$13&'[wORKBOOK1 NAME]SHEET1'!$B$2:$B$13,1,0),0)),"True","False")`

This must be entered as an array formula (While still in the formula bar hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

The if statement will check for the match and build a new binary array (1 for a match and 0 for no match), the MATCH formula then is simply checking if a match is found in that new array by searching for 1.